# pressing 'ctrl+alt+t' is not opening terminal ; how to fix it?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I was trying to install macbuntu in my pc. So I entered the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:docky-core/stable && apt-get update
```

then purged, installed then again purged `docky`. Then I found that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> stopped working. Then I also removed the `docky.desktop` file located in `~/.autoconfig/autostart/`. I also checked for the shortcuts in the settings but they are all fine. I use unity environment. Thus now <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> is not working. What should I do?

Comment: Might seem silly, but have you tried rebooting?

Comment: Did you check *Settings -> Keyboard -> Application Shortcuts* and make sure that Ctrl+Alt+T is assigned to open the terminal?

Comment: Definitely, I have tried rebooting and also checked the keyboard shortcuts(as mentioned in the question itself).

Comment: @Terrance Can you suggest anything else ??

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: @Terrance I was using 17.10 when this key stopped working  then I upgraded to 18.04 with the hope that the keys might start functioning .   :(

Comment: What terminal is Ctrl+Alt+T trying to open in the keyboard settings?

Comment: I have set x-terminal-emulator as default to open with Ctrl +Alt+T

Comment: OK, so I have to ask then.  You are using Xfce4 (Xubuntu) desktop then, right?  `x-terminal-emulator` is the default in Xubuntu.  It is called the same as `xfce4-terminal`.  If it can be called from a command line, it should be able to be called from Ctrl+Alt+T.  Other keyboard shortcuts are working, correct?